# Editable JComboBox firing ActionListener when losing focus

Tags: java, combobox, actionlistener

I am writing a class (`UIPromptComboBox`) that extends JComboBox. The combobox is editable and for one application of the class it is implemented with a controlling `ActionListener`.

Currently, when the combobox is edited it fires the `ActionListener` which is good. However this `ActionListener` is also fired when I deselect the combobox and I cannot distinguish between the two events nor do I want it to fire when the combobox is deselected.

Implementing Class

```
private void addUIField() {
        // Initialise and place combobox
        this.myGuiTextField = new UIPromptComboBox();
        myGuiTextField.setSize(COMBO_WIDTH, defaultHeight);
        GuiUtils.positionControl(myPanel, myGuiTextField, myTop, PROMPT_X_LOC);

        //Add action listener
        myGuiTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")) {
                    newUIcreated((UIPromptComboBox) evt.getSource());
                }
            }

            private void newUIcreated(UIPromptComboBox alteredGuiTextField) {
                try {
                    UIPrompt uip = alteredGuiTextField.getUIPrompt(((PowerPointTextItem) myPPTRef).getValue());
                    if (!simInfo.isInPrompts(uip)) {
                        simInfo.addUIPrompt(uip);
                        alteredGuiTextField.addNewUIPrompt(uip);
                    }
                } catch (MissingPowerpointItem ex) {
                    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Class that extends JComboBox

```
public class UIPromptComboBox extends JComboBox {

    public UIPromptComboBox(UIPrompt[] items) {
        super(items);
        this.setEditable(true);
    }

    public UIPromptComboBox() {
        this.setEditable(true);
        this.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * returns either the selected UI prompt or a new prompt using the example
     * text
     *
     * @param exampleText only used if new prompt is created
     * @return UI prompt selected
     */
    public UIPrompt getUIPrompt(String exampleText) {
        UIPrompt uIPrompt = null;
        Object returnedItem = this.getSelectedItem();
        if (returnedItem instanceof UIPrompt) {
            uIPrompt = (UIPrompt) returnedItem;
        } else if (returnedItem instanceof String) {
            uIPrompt = new UIPrompt((String) returnedItem, exampleText);
        }
        return uIPrompt;
    }

    public void addNewUIPrompt(UIPrompt newPrompt) {
        ActionListener[] actionListerners = this.getActionListeners();

        this.removeActionListener(this);
        this.addItem(newPrompt);
        this.setSelectedItem(newPrompt);

        for (ActionListener al : actionListerners) {
            this.addActionListener(al);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Used for displaying a report value sentence
     * i.e. a string that is not associated with UI Prompts
     * @param newText report value sentence
     */
    public void setText(String newText) {
        this.removeAllItems();
        this.addItem(newText);
        this.setSelectedItem(newText);
    }

    /**
     * For when the UI prompts can be added on construction
     *
     * @param currentUIs list of UI promts
     */
    public void addItems(UIPrompt[] currentUIs) {
        this.removeAllItems();
        DefaultComboBoxModel boxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(currentUIs);
        this.setModel(boxModel);
    }

}
```

The multiple firing due to losing focus is causing multiple objects to be created and added to the list. I think I may have implemented the `ActionListener` incorrectly. Thank you for your help

Comment: would it be okay to only the fire the event once you deselect the combobox? right now i didn't understand what exactly should happen and what is happening

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, thank you for reading my question. 

I would prefer that the ActionListener fired when the user pressed enter after editing the combobox rather than on deselecting. Currently the problem is that it fires both when enter is pressed and when another combobox is selected which is cause my code to repeat a significant number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now finally found the issue.

The displaying of the `UIPrompt` included the addition of a string that sometimes contained a new line character.

The action of clicking another field was triggering the render of the `UIPrompt` however when this contained a newline character it was triggering the `ActionListener` again. This what the reason for the repeated action of comboBoxEdited.

Answer (score 0):

as you stated you only want the event to fire if the user presses enter. a better way to implement that, would be using an keylistener instead of an action listener.

```
myGuiTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            newUIcreated((UIPromptComboBox) evt.getSource());
        }
    }

    private void newUIcreated(UIPromptComboBox alteredGuiTextField) {
           try {
                UIPrompt uip = alteredGuiTextField.getUIPrompt(((PowerPointTextItem) myPPTRef).getValue());
            if (!simInfo.isInPrompts(uip)) {
                simInfo.addUIPrompt(uip);
                alteredGuiTextField.addNewUIPrompt(uip);
            }
        } catch (MissingPowerpointItem ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

this should now only fire your event `newUIcreated`, once the users presses enter and at no other time. replace your action listener with this

Comment: Thank is a really good idea. However I just tried implementing it and the key event is not firing. Regardless of what key is pressed. Any ideas?

Comment: did you change the `combobox` to your components name? just updated in my code

Comment: I did, It is not a compile error, it is a problem with the listener not being activated

Comment: can you please add a simple `system.out.println("test");` before the if in the key listener? so you can see if it does enter the key listener

Comment: thank you so much for your kind suggestions. I have solved my issue.